# PHP glob() to list file that doesn't start with underscore?

Tags: php, regex

The standard glob() function usage is like

```
$dir = glob("*.txt");
foreach ($dir as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

using * as wildcard, but is there a way to negate it to ignore any file that starts with underscore like _something.txt? **I am trying to avoid using preg_match()** like

```
$dir = glob("*.txt");
foreach ($dir as $filename) {
    if (! preg_match("^_+", $filename, $match) { // doesn't show if 1st char is _
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
    }
}
```

but **instead use glob()'s own regex to avoid loading unnecessary files in the first place**, assuming this will be faster.

Comment: RegEx states `^` as negative to what follows. That will probably work. I never use `glob`, but if it accept basic RegEx it should be possible with `[^_].*?\.txt`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This'll do it.

```
$dir = glob("[!_]*.txt");
foreach ($dir as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Here is a compilation of special characters in a glob() pattern: http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/

Comment: @ComFreek Thank you for the pattern link, wasn't able to find that on official php.net, have a great New Yeark!

Comment: Great solution! Which is fastest of these two answers? My guess is this one.

Answer (score 6):

No need for a regex.

```
$files = array_filter(glob('*.txt'), function ($filename) {
  return $filename[0] != '_';
});
```

Comment: Great idea, but it will load all the files first by glob(), then process it. I am trying to apply negating regex in glob() itself, so it can be faster (just assuming) and doesn't load all the files in the first place.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It does support negations. See Dave's answer (latest edit) or [this reference](http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/).