# Using glob() to get all files not starting with given text

Tags: php, regex, file-io

I understand how the following will return all files with a `.txt` extension. I would like to do the same but exclude those that start with 'exclude'?  For instance, `some/path/exclude_somefile.txt` shouldn't be included.

```
$files = glob('/some/path/*.txt');
```

How can I do it?

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/20860379/ and the other one too on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GLOB_BRACE parameter.

This will skip all files beginning with "_"

```
$images = glob(__DIR__.'/img/errors/[!{_}]*.*', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly certain that `glob()` uses a regex pattern, so you should be to filter it out using regex syntax. Try this:

```
$files = glob('/some/path/(?!exclude_)*.txt');
```

This uses a negative look-around, I'm not sure if `glob()` will understand it, but give it a shot.

EDIT:

`glob()` does not support high level regex functions such as look-arounds. Here's my suggestion.

```
$files = glob('/some/path/*.txt');

foreach($files as $key => $filename)
{
    if(strpos($filename, "/exclude_"))
        unset($files[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Is this any better than `$files = glob("/some/path/[!exclude_]*.txt");`?  What is the difference?